# Hotmail Problem with margin top

Tags: css

I have an element in my email template:

```
<div style="height:20px; width:320px; margin-top:370px; margin-left:240px;">
</div>
```

In gmail every thing is ok. But in hotmail `margin-top:370px;` not working. I cant see `margin-top:370px;` in firebug. How can I solve the problem with hotmail.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In Hotmail in every browser, or any particular browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert an empty element above this div, that way margin will work

Comment: margin-top:370px; line couldnt view by hotmail. (I cant see this line in firebug)

Comment: Don't know why, just add empty element with 370 height and it will work :)

Answer (score 3):

Hotmail doesn't seem to support margin-top or margin. Avoid those properties. Try to fix so that you use padding-top etc. Or convert everything to margin-bottom.

- http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/7_tips_and_tricks_regarding_margins_and_padding_in_html_emails
- http://www.forestpath.org/notes/html/email

Comment: Using `padding` instead solved the problem for me. Thanks a lot!